# How to show day of the week in UIDatePickerModeDate for UIDatePicker?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to show day of the week in UIDatePickerModeDate just like UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime. Thanks in advance.

-Joey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do this with UIDatePicker.  You can however just create a custom UIPicker with days of the week as the elements.